# Loading spatialite with python3's module under Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, spatialite

I installed spatialite's Python module using pip:

`pip install spatialite`

I copied the mod_spatialite.dll found on https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/index.html into my windows/system32 folder (I have Python 3 32bits)

I have the error message

`spatialite.connection.LoadExtensionError: Failed to load SpatiaLite extension. Verify that your python module sqlite3 has load_extension support and check that libspatialite is installed. Tried extension names: mod_spatialite, mod_spatialite.so, mod_spatialite.dylib`

Comment: maybe this answer for C# can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44283086/3154189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  this https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/ address download `mod_spatialite`, unzip it and copy in `system32`